# C++ template meta-programming: find out if variadic type list contains value

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I'm trying to write a function that evaluates to true if a parameter passed at run-time is contained in a list of ints set up at compile-time. I tried adapting the print example here: [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variadic-function-templates-c/#:~:text=Variadic%20templates%20are%20class%20or,help%20to%20overcome%20this%20issue](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variadic-function-templates-c/#:%7E:text=Variadic%20templates%20are%20class%20or,help%20to%20overcome%20this%20issue).

And have tried this:

```
bool Contains(int j) { return false; }

template<int i, int... is>
bool Contains(int j) { return i == j || Contains<is...>(j); }
```

However, it gives me a compiler error saying "'Contains': no matching overloaded function found".

I've tried fiddling with angle-brackets but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You need a *template* as recursion base instead! Or try a fold expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that the recursive call is

```
Contains<is...>(j)
```

this looks for *template* overloads of `Contains`.

Your base case:

```
bool Contains(int j) { return false; }
```

is not a template.  So the final call, when the pack is empty, of:

```
Contains<>(j)
```

cannot find the non-template.

---

There are a few easy fixes.

The best version requires a version of C++ greater than [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11); 17 I think:

```
template<int... is>
bool Contains(int j) { return ((is == j) || ...); }
```

This one is short, simple and clear.

The simple pre-[c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) ones generate O(n^2) total symbol length without jumping through extensive hoops.  The [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) one is O(n) total symbol length, much nicer.  The [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) one is obtuse, but also O(n) total symbol length.

So here are some [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) ones that are suitable for modest lengths of packs:

None of the [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) ones support empty packs:

```
template<class=void>
bool Contains(int j) { return false; }

template<int i, int... is>
bool Contains(int j) { return i == j || Contains<is...>(j); }
```

It relies on the fact that the first overload will never be selected except on an empty pack.  (It is, due to a quirk in the standard, illegal to put any check that the pack is empty).

Another way that does not support empty packs is:

```
template<int i>
bool Contains(int j) { return i==j; }

template<int i0, int i1, int... is>
bool Contains(int j) { return Contains<i0>(j) || Contains<i1, is...>(j); }
```

which is more explicit than the first one.

The technique to get the total symbol length below O(n^2) involves doing a binary tree repacking of the parameter pack of integers.  It is tricky and confusing, and I'd advise against it.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/Wr9Mzb1eP).

Finally, here is a hacky one in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) that avoids the O(n^2) symbol length problem:

```
template<int...is>
bool Contains(int j) {
  using discard=int[];
  bool result = false;
  (void)discard{0,((void)(result = result || (is==j)),0)...};
  return result;
}
```

don't ask how it works.  It is a technique that [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) rendered obsolete on purpose.

Comment: Could you hint to the standard stating size check being illegal? What's the point of not being able to use `sizeof...(is) == 0`?

Comment: @Aconcagua Any template that takes a parameter pack must have a valid specialization with a non-empty parameter pack, or your program is ill-formed no diagnostic required.  This was probably intended to allow compilers to check for pathological code where pack expansion always generates garbage, but as a side effect makes static_asserts that the pack is empty illegal.

Comment: @Bob__ `c` works `b` does not.  Fixing `b`.

Comment: That would make the fold expression approach invalid, too, wouldn't it? There's no specialisation with non-empty parameter pack... Or how do you define *'non-empty'*? Is that restricted to static_assert only? Assuming we'd want empty set to contain *any* value (not really meaningful, I know...) – `return ( (j == is) || ... ) || sizeof...(is) == 0;` should then be fine?

Comment: I might be missing something, but can't you just fake the fold expression with initialization in C++11?

Comment: @PasserBy Sure, but that is awkward and ugly!  I guess that does get rid of O(n^2) tho.

Comment: @PasserBy Hmm, that requires C++14 I think; maybe we could hack it further with a helper function to get the initial false result.  But C++11 constexpr is limited to a single expression.

Comment: Ah... I didn't think you'd want `constexpr`. AFAIK you can't make the C++11 version `constexpr`. Also the compound literal might be a bit iffy.

Comment: @PasserBy Compound literal is I think legal even in C.  `constexpr` is blocked in C++11 because you can't even repeatedly modify local variables in C++11 (I have a version that uses a default function argument for `result`, still doesn't pass C++11).  The live link contains version macros and compiles clean in each standard version from 11 to 17 now.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont What do you say about the point `static_assert(sizeof...(args) == 0)` in this answer?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71905195/wrap-a-function-that-takes-stdfunctiondoubledoule-in-order-to-pass-functio/71905543#71905543 **Is it ill formed already?**

Comment: @Const It doesn't violate the valid specialization requirement of the C++ standard, which applies at the template level (and there is a specific one about accepting at least one non-empty pack at that level).  I don't know the requirements for `constexpr if` branches.  I'd guess it is fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve what you want with a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) (C++17):

```
template<int... is>
bool Contains(int j) { return ((is == j) || ...);
```

Called like so:

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << Contains<1, 2, 3>(1) << "\n"; // true
std::cout << std::boolalpha << Contains<1, 2, 3>(4);         // false
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5qT78nrao)