# Wrap a function that takes std::function<double(doule)> in order to pass functions that take more arguments

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

## Problem

I have a function `double subs(std::function<double(double)> func)`, and I want to wrap it in a new function that looks like this

```
template<typename... Args> double subsWrap(std::function<double(Args... args)> func)
```

that applies `subs` to some function that takes more inputs as

```
subs( subs( subs( ... func(...) ) ) )
```

with each `subs` applied to only one of the arguments of `func` at a time.

### Minimal example

Let's say that we have a function

```
auto subs = [] (std::function<double(double)> func){return func(2) + func(5.3);};
```

and we want to apply it to

```
auto f2=[](double x, double y){return std::sin(x*std::exp(x/y)); };
```

as

```
subs( [&f2](double y){ return  subs( [&y,&f2](double x){ return f2(x,y); } ); } )
```

For `f2`, this is easy, so there is no need for a wrapper. However, if we want to do the same thing for a function of a greater number of arguments (e.g. `double(double,double,double,double,double)`) things start to become complicated.

There has to be a way to do this automatically, but I am not even sure how to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using variadic lambdas together with `std::is_invocable` type trait to terminate recursion?

```
template<class Fn>
double subs_wrap(Fn func) {
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<Fn, double>)
        return subs(func);
    else
        return subs([=](double x) {
            return subs_wrap(
                [=](auto... xs) -> decltype(func(x, xs...))
                { return func(x, xs...); }
            );
        });
}
```

Here an explicit return type specification for a lambda is needed to propagate "invocability" property. `[=](auto... xs) { return func(x, xs...); }` is formally invocable with any number of arguments, no matter whether `func(x, xs...)` is invocable or not. When the return type is specified explicitly with `decltype`, SFINAE jumps in.

With this implementation, both expressions

```
subs([=](double y) { 
    return subs([=](double x) {
        return f2(x, y);
    });
});
```

and

```
subs_wrap(f2);
```

will produce the same result.

It's interesting to note that with `-O3` optimization both GCC and Clang can [optimize all this code away](https://godbolt.org/z/z5TqrsnvM) and replace `subs_wrap(f2)` with a compile-time constant. With similar code written using `std::function` arguments they don't do it.

---

> How do we do the unpacking if we want to pass arguments to subs (different for each recursion)

Here is a way to achieve this with a slight modification of code:

```
template<class Fn, class P, class... Ps>
double subs_wrap(Fn func, P p, Ps... ps) {
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<Fn, double>) {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Ps) == 0);
        return subs(func, p);
    }
    else {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Ps) > 0);
        return subs([=](double x) {
            return subs_wrap(
                [=](auto... xs) -> decltype(func(x, xs...))
                { return func(x, xs...); },
                ps...);
        }, p);
    }
}

subs_wrap(f2, p1, p2);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. By the way, how do we do the unpacking if we want to pass arguments to subs (different for each recursion)?

Comment: @dkaramit Could you please be more specific about passing arguments to `subs`? Do you want same arguments for the whole recursion tree or different ones for each call? An example would be helpful.

Comment: Let's say that the subs function is `double subs(std::function<double(double)> func, double p){return func(2) + func(p);};`. How would subs_wrap would look like for p to be different for each call to subs? For example make `subs_wrap(std::function<double(double,double)> func, double p1, double p2)` return `subs( [&f2](double y){ return  subs( [&y,&f2](double x){ return f2(x,y); }, p1); }, p2)`.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally posted an incomplete comment, and edited while you posted your answer. So this is the question again: Let's say that the subs function is `double subs(std::function<double(double)> func, double p){return func(2) + func(p);};`. How would subs_wrap would look like for p to be different for each call to subs? For example make `subs_wrap(std::function<double(double,double)> func, double p1, double p2)` return `subs( [&f2](double y){ return  subs( [&y,&f2](double x){ return f2(x,y); }, p1); }, p2)`.

Comment: @dkaramit What about this: https://godbolt.org/z/hf6Woj3sK ?

Comment: Yes, perfect! Thank you for this.

Comment: @dkaramit Could you please share motivation behind this problem? By your profile I guess it's related to physics and having background in theoretical physics myself I'm curious about the underlying problem.

Comment: Well, I have built a simple local adaptive integrator [github](https://github.com/dkaramit/LAInt), in order to calculate some 1-dimensional integrals I needed. However, I realized that using lambdas and recursion it can be made to calculate multiple integrals as well (despite the fact the I didn't know how to do it). It is not the most efficient way to do these kinds of integrals, but it is helpful to know.

Comment: I wonder the comment from @Yakk - Adam Nevraumont from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71797216/c-template-meta-programming-find-out-if-variadic-type-list-contains-value/71797386#comment126878359_71797386 
 **Doing `static_assert(sizeof...(args) == 0)` for therefore dangerous?? isn't it?**

Comment: @Const I don't think so. Assertion of this kind is illegal/dangerous if it makes *all* specializations invalid. But here `static_assert` is inside the `if constexpr` branch. Obviously, we do have valid specializations with non-empty `Ps...` pack - the first `if constexpr` is not taken in that case.